# Jquery-UI greedy droppable fire event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Im using jquery-UI droppable, When I drag the small green box over the blue ones from top to bottom everything works as I want but when I drag the box from bot to top the parent box trigger the over event and gets highlighted, i want that just one element being highligthed at same time, one of the siblings or the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">Drag me</div>

<div class="drop">Drophere
    <div class="drop">Drophere</div>
    <div class="drop">Drophere</div>
    <div class="drop">Drophere</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".box").draggable();
$(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".box",
    hoverClass: "drophere",
    greedy:true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Deivid11/44bg1bz4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can check on `over` event if a child `.drop` has class `.drophere` and if so, remove `.drophere` from the parent. Like this:

```
over: function (e, ui) {
    $('.drop .drophere').parent().removeClass('drophere');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p1wjk56h/1/